# Compare two lists and update value one list value to other angular5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two list of objects

List1:
TotalEmployers-

```
 [{EmployerId: 1,Name:"Rick", Checked :false}, {EmployerId: 2,Name:"John", Checked :false},{EmployerId: 3,Name:"Maddy", Checked :false}]
```

List2:
UpdatedEmployer

```
[{EmployerId: 1,Name:"Rick"},{EmployerId: 2,Name:"John"}]
```

How to update list1 checked value to true based on records in list2

Final output :

List1:
TotalEmployers-

```
[{EmployerId: 1,Name:"Rick", Checked :true}, {EmployerId: 2,Name:"John", Checked :true},{EmployerId: 3,Name:"Maddy", Checked :false}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be the most compact code:

```
TotalEmployers.forEach(x => {
   x.Checked = UpdatedEmployer.some(y => y.EmployerId === x.EmployerId);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ***[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)*** operator:

```
TotalEmployers.map(employee=> {
   return employee.Checked = UpdatedEmployer.some(cobay => cobay.EmployerId=== employee.EmployerId);
});
```

Here is a snippet for your case :

```js
TotalEmployers = [{EmployerId: 1,Name:"Rick", Checked :false}, {EmployerId: 2,Name:"John", Checked :false},{EmployerId: 3,Name:"Maddy", Checked :false}];

UpdatedEmployer = [{EmployerId: 1,Name:"Rick"},{EmployerId: 2,Name:"John"}];




TotalEmployers.map(employee=> {
   return employee.Checked = UpdatedEmployer.some(cobay => cobay.EmployerId=== employee.EmployerId);
});


console.log(TotalEmployers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your `TotalEmployers`, if an employee in `UpdatedEmployer` contains the id, set to true or false by `some` method

```
TotalEmployers.forEach(function(employee)
{        
    employee.checked = UpdatedEmployer.some(function (item) {
           return item.EmployerId == employee.EmployerId;
       });

})
```

Comment: foreach in javascript? :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array. As you can see in the documentation, it returns a new array with modifications applied on each elements as per the callback function passed to it.

```
TotalEmployers = TotalEmployers.map(e => {
   e.Checked = UpdatedEmployer.some(cobay => cobay.id === e.id);
});
```

Comment: This won't work. Your `map` function doesn't return anything, so you're gonna end up with an array full of `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Sets in javascript

```
const updatedEmployersSet = new Set(UpdatedEmployers.map(e => e.EmployerId));

TotalEmployers.forEach(e => e.Checked = updatedEmployersSet.has(e.EmployerId))
```